# Add simple Nivo Slider to wordpress site

Tags: plugins

I have a wordpress website, on the front page i have an area below the main menu which    takes a post and displays it along with an image, what i would like to do is swap this box for the nivo slider.

```
http://79.170.40.241/shaddersafrica.com/
```

The problem is, this area of the website isn't controlled through the admin area and although i have the simple-nivo-slider plugin installed, i don't know if it is possible to place it in place of the current post area and if so how i would do that.

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add Simple Nivo Slider to a post you can use this shortcode `[snivo]`
-- this is from the instructions at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-nivo-slider/installation/

If you want to place it on your homepage ... you can edit your theme files (probably content-single.php) and this code  `<?php if (function_exists('simple_nivo_slider')) simple_nivo_slider(); ?>`

The simplest ... is create a Page  (WordPress Admin > Add New Page) and add the `[snivo]`

then go to Wordpress Admin > Settings > General and Choose your new page
see also: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page